# gcallowverylargeobjects not solving dimension limitation in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dimensions, gcallowverylargeobjects

In my C# code, I need to include a matrix in size 13805*55223; which I believe is not that large.

To overcome RAM limitation, I am using gcAllowVeryLargeObjects, and I have also unchecked prefer 32-Bit system.

Doing all of that, I still face "Array dimension exceeds supported range" error!

I appreciate any help to handle this issue.

Comment: can you show us your code

Comment: `13'805*55'223 = 762'353'515` so if you have as much as int values in that you will have ~ 3GB of memory used already...

Comment: Are you sure your app is really running at 64 bits? Try looking at [`Environment.Is64BitProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You are doing something wrong but it is going to take a psychic to guess what it might be.  Just don't, use a jagged array.  It not only avoids the limitation, it is also much faster.

Comment: The code is simple like:
double[,] a = new double[13805,55223];

Comment: I have that much double actually, and it needs more than 3GB for sure. I have available RAM, but the problem is with array size.

Comment: I tested, and I am sure I am running at 64 bits.

Comment: If you use double values instead of int values, you need ~6GB of memory

Answer (score 3):

Please try if the following program works on your system.
It creates an onedimensional int array with the size 13805*55223.
For these array size are ~3GB of memory reserved and works fine on my system.

program.cs:

```
using System;

namespace arrtest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is64BitProcess :"+  Environment.Is64BitProcess);
            int [] arr = new int[13805*55223];
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you Tonirush!
I am just managing the error according to your suggestion now. The only change is that I had "gcAllowVeryLargeObjects" in a separate app.config, but now have all in a single app.config!
I am not sure if that was the reason for my problem!

Comment: If you use double (64 bit value) instead of int (32 bit value), you need the double amount of memory (~6GB).

Comment: So you need at least 8GB main memory, or better a system with 16GB main memory. I can't run a program that uses 6GB memory on my 8GB system because i have only 5GB free.